# Sum/Difference Identity Formula Question

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Wouldn't this be, per the sum/difference identity formula, $\cos (\frac{13\pi}{5}-\frac{\pi} {5})$ which is $\cos (\frac{12\pi}{5})$?

Comment: You have the right idea. However, the equation has $13\pi/15$, whereas your solution uses $13\pi/5$ (that is, the denominators are different). Based on the equation as written, the solution should be $$\cos\left(\frac{13\pi}{15}+\left(-\frac{\pi}{5}\right)\right) = \cos\left(\frac{13\pi}{15}-\frac{3\pi}{15}\right) = \cos\frac{10\pi}{15}= \cos\frac{2\pi}{3}$$

Comment: ZAHHHHHHHHHHHH i made a typo in my notebook. Thank you for picking that out! I thought I was going crazy

Answer (score 1):

Per your question, its correct. Simply use the formula: $\cos A\cos B - \sin A\sin B = \cos(A+B)$. Use this equation with $A = \dfrac{13\pi}{5}, B = \dfrac{-\pi}{5}$.